# Why strange symbols appended to string values?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I have a column read from a csv file by pandas, and the value is set to the variable 'app_name':

```
app_name = 'Do Not Feed the Monkey‪s‬'
```

Before I put this value into a dict, in PyCharm it shows as a normal string, observed in the debugger:

```
app_name = (str)'Do Not Feed the Monkey‪s‬'
```

However, after I put it into a dict in python:

```
data_dict['游戏名称'] = app_name
```

Then in the debuger, there are additional two symbols '\u202as\u202c':

```
data_dict = {dict: 1} {'游戏名称': 'Do Not Feed the Monkey\u202as\u202c'}
'游戏名称' = {str} 'Do Not Feed the Monkey‪s‬'
```

But if you click the internal structure of the dict, it still shows as a normal string, without any additional symbols:

```
'游戏名称' = {str} 'Do Not Feed the Monkey‪s‬'
```

What's the issue?

Also, if I directly copy the string with my mouse from the excel into PyCharm editor, i can see strange symbol at the end of the string, but if I paste it in other places, i.e. browser or here  at stackoverflow text box, I can't see the symbols. Please see the attached strange symbols directly copied from excel:

[image]

How to avoid those strange symbols when read from csv by Pandas? This is the first time I saw those strange symbols.  The usual 'strip' function is unable to remove them.

Comment: perhaps is the where you're getting the data from uses different encoding. Common encodings are UTF-8, Latin-1 (also known as ISO-8859-1), and Windows-1251. For example, some databases might use utf-8, but your system might use ISO. Perhaps try something like pd.read_csv('x.csv', encoding ='utf-8', errors = 'ignore')?

Comment: @Docuemada I already have the encoding='utf-8', but no errors = 'ignore'. Does the 'errors' parameter work here?

Comment: If I recall (if I have the syntax correct), ignore would simply not write anything for the unknown characters, skipping over the \u202as\u202c,

Comment: I tried, and it only has 'error_bad_lines', not 'errors'.

Comment: perhaps it's ignore_error = True,  but this is all assuming that this is the root problem. I wasn't 100% sure, hence the comment, not the answer

Answer (score 0):

The extra characters are for [directional formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text) of text:

```py
>>> s = '\u202as\u202c'
>>> print(s)
s
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> for c in s:print(ud.name(c))
... 
LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
LATIN SMALL LETTER S
POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
```

Presumably these usually invisible characters are already present in the spreadsheet that you are processing.  You can remove them using [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```py
>>> s = 'Do Not Feed the Monkey\u202as\u202c'
>>> translation_table = str.maketrans({ord(c): None for c in '\u202a\u202c'})
>>> s.translate(translation_table)
'Do Not Feed the Monkeys'
```